# Jquery Datepicker: date format is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to **display date in dd/mm/yyyy** and **the value should be store as yyyymmdd** in a variable.

**dd/mm/yyyy is displayed correct** but the value is not storing in format **yyyymmdd it is showing as  yyyymd**

like if I select 02/03/2022 it is storing as 202232 which is incorrect as it has to be store as 20220302.

```
  var strDateTimeEntry;
   $(function () {
     $("#entrydate").datepicker({
       //date format for displaying
       dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    });
   $("#entrydate").change(function () {
      var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
      //date format for storing
       strDateTimeEntry = date.getFullYear() + "" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "" + date.getDate();
     $("#EntryDateDisplay").text(strDateTimeEntry);
       alert(strDateTimeEntry);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pad your month and day.

```
strDateTimeEntry = date.getFullYear() + "" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + "" + date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
```

Here's a fiddle example that takes a Date object and displays output in the required format.

https://jsfiddle.net/udcybs6z/